# C++ template operator overloading not working

Tags: c++, templates, operators, operator-overloading

I have this function:

```
void plusQueue(){
    PrioQueue<int> *a = new PrioQueue<int>(2);
    PrioQueue<int> *b = new PrioQueue<int>(2);

    a->push(3);
    b->push(5);
    a->push(7);
    b->push(2); 

    cout << "a"<<endl;
    a->print();
    cout << "b"<<endl;
    b->print();
    cout<<"Samenvoegen\n";
    PrioQueue<int> *c = new PrioQueue<int>(4);
    c = a + b;
    c->print();
}
```

And this line:

```
c = a + b;
```

gives some problems. I get this message:

```
main.cpp:71:13: error: invalid operands of types 'PrioQueue<int>*' and 'PrioQueue<int>*' to binary 'operator+'
```

It's an overloaded operator in my template class:

```
PrioQueue operator +(PrioQueue a) {
    PrioQueue temp = *this;

    T *bottom = a.getBottom();
    T *top = a.getTop();

    for (T *element = bottom; element < top; element++) {
        temp.push(*element);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: can you ad pointers like that? a, b, c, are **pointers to `PrioQueue`** not `PrioQueues`. `try *c = *a + *b;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, you're dynamically allocating the objects, so `a`, `b` and `c` are pointers. You can't add pointers.

If you really want to keep the pointers, then you need to deference them to access the objects:

```
*c = *a + *b;
```

and remember to delete the objects once you're done with them; your code leaks like a leaky thing.

More likely, you want the objects to be automatic:

```
PrioQueue<int> a(2);
PrioQueue<int> b(2);

// populate them

PrioQueue<int> c = a + b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you say that you get a PrioQueue and not a pointer.
try `*a + *b`